# Slow array operations after DB resultset

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I need help optimizing my PowerShell script.

```
$sorted = @()
$firsttime = 0
$j = 0
$zaehler = $results.Count-1

for ($i=0; $i -le $results.Count-1; $i++) {
    $j = $i+1
    while ($results.GUID[$i] -eq $results.GUID[$j]) {
        $klassen = ""
        $rec = $results | where {$_.GUID -eq $results.GUID[$i]}

        if ($firsttime -eq 0 -or !$sorted.GUID.contains($rec[0].GUID)) {
            $firsttime = 1
            foreach ($item in $rec.Klasse) {
                if ($klassen -eq "") {
                    $klassen += $item
                } else {
                    if (!$klassen.Contains($item)) {
                        $klassen += "," + $item
                    }
                }
            }
            $rec[0].Klasse = $klassen
            $sorted += $rec[0]
        }
        $j = $j+1
    }
    Write-Host ($i/$zaehler).ToString("P") "von Schule" $schule
}
if (!$sorted) {
    $results
} else {
    $sorted
}
```

Basically in my resultset (`$results`) I got duplicate lines of teachers and the only difference is the class ("Klasse/Klassen") they are teaching at.
To minimize the output I am checking if the first GUID is the same as the second and then the script appends the second class to the first one. So the `$sorted` array has just one line per teacher with a comma-seperated string which shows all classes.

Sample line of `$results`:

```
@{
    GUID={1234567-1234-1234-1234-1234567}; 
    userrole=teacher;
    Vorname=Max;
    Nachname=Mustermann;
    Geburtstag=01.01.2000;
    Klasse=9A; 
    Schule=123456
}
@{
    GUID={1234567-1234-1234-1234-1234567};
    userrole=teacher;
    Vorname=Max;
    Nachname=Mustermann;
    Geburtstag=01.01.2000;
    Klasse=9B; 
    Schule=123456
}
```

Sample line of `$sorted[0]`:

```
@{
    GUID={1234567-1234-1234-1234-1234567};
    userrole=teacher;
    Vorname=Max;
    Nachname=Mustermann;
    Geburtstag=01.01.2000;
    Klasse=9A,9B,9C,5A;
    Schule=123456
}
```

The sorting process (check if contains, foreach `$item`, add to `$klassen`) is pretty slow.

I would be very grateful for any kind of ideas how to optimize the script.

Comment: Have you used `Measure-Command` to identify which part actually is the slow one? What does "slow" mean, seconds, minutes, hours? How much data are you dealing with?

Comment: well, the sample resultset contains around 400 entries. The sorting process takes around 5 minutes. Only for one school. Because Im no PS-expert I thought that maybe there's another way of editing, appending, and well dealing with hashtables in generel and sorting-processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
$results | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $_
} | Group-Object GUID | ForEach-Object {
    $teacher = $_.Group
    $teacher | Select-Object -First 1 -Exclude Klasse -Property *, @{n='Klasse';e={
        $teacher | Select-Object -Expand Klasse
    }}
}
```

Convert your hashtables into custom objects, group them by GUID, then replace the original "Klasse" property with a new one containing an array of the values from all objects in that group, and select the first result.

Should `$results` already be a list of objects you can skip the first `ForEach-Object`:

```
$results | Group-Object GUID | ForEach-Object {
    $teacher = $_.Group
    $teacher | Select-Object -First 1 -Exclude Klasse -Property *, @{n='Klasse';e={
        $teacher | Select-Object -Expand Klasse
    }}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I had to skip the first part, cause $results already is a collection of PSObjects. I managed to implement your part into my script, the results seems to be a bit messy and actually it has the same speed as my first solution.

Comment: Are you certain that the result processing and not the database query is your bottleneck? How did you verify?

Comment: WOW, wait. I didnt realize, I had to remove my whole for-loop. It seems to work SUPERFAST. Can you help me seperate each class with a comma "," ?

Comment: Simply join them with commas: `($teacher | Select-Object -Expand Klasse) -join ','`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted: An easier method to organize the array, instead of 5 minutes it takes now like a few seconds. And I learned a lot about Powershell today. Thank you so much!